# Successful EKS Cluster Upgrade with Unmanaged Nodgroups: Alternatives to Velero?

Tags: cluster-computing, upgrade, eksctl

AWS Eks cluster with unmanaged nodgroups (eksctl) upgrade from v1.22 to v1.23

Trying to migrate eks cluster with unmanaged nodgroups (eksctl) v1.22 to v1.23 using Velero. Resources spin up normally, however without any data (pv and pvc are empty). Any suggestion in this case? Other ways to upgrade eks cluster with unmanaged nodgroups? Thank you